# Where can I find the trackbar winforms control in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm currently studying C# but I can't find trackbar.

[image]

Trackbar is included in "System.Windows.Forms" but I can not find it.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community 15.7.5 version.

**Where can I find the trackbar control in Visual Studio 2017?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: It's called "Slider Control".

Comment: @DaImTo I'll say. No Trackbar found in C # wintform.

Comment: @BrunoBieri No Slider Control found too. ㅠㅠ

Comment: @BrunoBieri No, Slider is for WPF. Trackbar is a standard WinForms component https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Esk It seems you have a little WinForms components. I have at least 50 under "All Windows Forms". Are you sure you selected Windows Forms development under Visual Studio Installer options?

Comment: @DaImTo Just because you didn't understand the question, it doesn't necessarly that it is unclear. I perfectly understood what OP is asking.

Comment: Try right click in toolbox and select reset toolbox

Comment: @Teejay the screenshot shows components filtered by "tr"

Comment: @Teejay Everything was installed except SQL Server Express and F# Desktop Language Support. ㅠㅠ

Comment: @stuartd Yes, but the title and the question clearly say that it is searching for Trackbar component. We are not kids reading an image-only book.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

Right click on Toolbox, select "Choose Items.."

under ".NET Framework Components" , scrool down to find 'Trackbar', it should be selectable via the tickbox, select the tickbox next to 'Trackbar' then OK.

Also

Tools --> Options --> Windows Forms Designer --> General --> Toolbox, Automatically Populate Toolbox --> True, OK